# Get user info from database

Tags: database, jsp

I am trying to validate a user login info with what I have in my database but when I try to run my code I keep on getting errors

This is my login.jsp page where I am working on the vaildation of the username and password In my table I have CID which I am using as the username any modification can be done to my code to make it run?

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%!
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement ps1, ps2;
    public void jspInit()
    {
        try
        {
            //loading the driver
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            //establish the connection
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/ProjectDB", "admin1", "1234");
            //create statement object
            ps1 = con.prepareStatement("select count(*) from customers where username = ? and password=?");
            ps2 = con.prepareStatement("select * from customers");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
%>
<%
    String param = request.getParameter("s1");
    if(param =="link")
    {
        ResultSet rs = ps2.executeQuery();
        out.println("<table>");
        while(rs.next())
        {
            out.println("<tr>");
            out.println("<td>"+rs.getString(1)+"</td>");
            out.println("<td>"+rs.getString(2)+"</td");
            out.println("</tr>");
        }
        out.println("</table>");
        rs.close();
    }
    else
    {
        //write jdbc code for authentication
        String user = request.getParameter("uname");
        String pass = request.getParameter("pwd");
        //set form data as param value
        ps1.setString(1,user);
        ps1.setString(2,pass);
        //excute the query
        ResultSet rs = ps1.executeQuery();
        int cnt = 0;
        if (rs.next())
            cnt = rs.getInt(1);
        if(cnt == 0)
            out.println("<b><i><font color=red>Invalid credential</fonr></i></b>");
        else
        {
            out.println("<form><fieldset style= width:25%; >");
            out.println("<b><i><font color=red>valid credential..</fonr></i></b><br>");
            out.println("<b><i><font size=6 color=blue>Welcome to My Page</fonr></i></b>");
            out.println("</fieldset></form>");
        }
    }
%>
<%!
    public void jspDestroy()
    {
        try
        {
            //colse
            ps1.close();
            ps2.close();
            con.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
%>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what errors are you seeing?

Comment: @jsotola java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.PreparedStatement.setString(int, String)" because "this.ps1" is null

Comment: You have your initializations in `jspInit` but i don't see you calling that method, so properly this why your objects are null.

Comment: Something wrong withe database connection that prevents your code to execute.

Comment: @JamalCrawford please add the error message to the question above ... it does not belong in a comment ... this site is not a forum